# How to reduce line spacing in bulleted list in Streamlit?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, markdown, streamlit

How do I reduce the line spacing between bullet points in st.markdown?

Code

```
st.markdown('- Item 1')
st.markdown('- Item 2')
st.markdown('- Item 3')
```

Current Output (would like to reduce the space as indicated)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the text inside the same markdown element, you can get something like this, which is a bit closer (items 4 & 5):

[image: markdown space]

```py
import streamlit as st

st.markdown("- Item 1")
st.markdown("- Item 2")
st.markdown("- Item 3")

st.markdown("- Item 4  \n- Item 5  ")
```